# How do I get rid of Unresolved external symbol "private: static char" error in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unresolved-external

I have a feeling that I am missing something really dumb here, but still: I have this annoying "external symbol" error in the game engine I am writing:

Basically I wanna create a class that reads a path in some global variables (so I don't have to send them all over the place). I used NFD(nativefiledialog) from github to open files. I tested it before this directly in main.cpp but the problems occured only after putting it in a class.

https://github.com/mlabbe/nativefiledialog

Paths.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <nfd.h>

namespace RW {
    class Paths {
    private:
        static nfdchar_t *gamePath;
        static nfdresult_t result;
    public:
        static void chooseGamePath();
    };
}
```

Paths.cpp

```
#include "Paths.h"

namespace RW {
    nfdchar_t Paths::*gamePath = NULL;
    nfdresult_t Paths::result;

    void Paths::chooseGamePath()
    {
        result = NFD_OpenDialog(NULL, NULL, &gamePath);;
        std::cout << "Please choose the location of the warcraft's exe file!" << std::endl;

        if (result == NFD_OKAY) {
            std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << gamePath << std::endl;
            free(gamePath);
        }
        else if (result == NFD_CANCEL) {
            std::cout << "User pressed cancel." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error: " << NFD_GetError() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static char * RW::Paths::gamePath" (?gamePath@Paths@RW@@0PADA) Half-an Engine  D:\Programozás\Repositories\Warcraft-II-HD\Half-an Engine\Paths.obj 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ class with static pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033649/)

Comment: are you sure Paths.cpp is getting compiled? when I copy/pasted this into a single file it worked just fine

Comment: @aaron Yea. If you do not run this in a class it works just fine, but I am pretty sure it is getting compiled because VIsual Studio said so. anyway Remy Lebeau already fixed the issue(at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cpp file, this line:

```
nfdchar_t Paths::*gamePath = NULL;
```

Declares a **pointer-to-member** named `gamePath` that can point only at a member of the `Paths` class which is of type `nfdchar_t`.

But that is not what you declared the `gamePath` member as in the `Paths` class. You declared it as just a simple (static) `nfdchar_t*` pointer instead.

Change that line to this instead:

```
nfdchar_t* Paths::gamePath = NULL;
```

That declares a variable named `gamePath` that is a member of the `Paths` class, and is of type `nfdchar_t*`.  That matches your declaration of `gamePath` in the `Paths` class declaration.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling that the fix would be something dumb like this :)). Anyway, I was wondering... what is the difference between these two declarations ?

Comment: @SzokeLori the second version defines what you were looking for, a member variable of the class `Path`, having it's type `nfdchar_t*`. The second one defines a pointer to any member variable of class `Path` with type `nfdchar_t`. In other word, the second is a member pointer, while the first is a pointer-to-member.

Comment: This is the problem with right-aligning your asterisks. Right-alignment zealots list a couple of arcane cases where left-alignment rubs up against the grammar, but examples like this question do the same thing and are far more common/obvious. Left-align!